# dataDriven excel - ant via commandLine( testng ant webdriver)

Tags: java, selenium, ant

I can run my tests via Ant in IDE.

But, While i try to run it from Command Line - it fails, because cant find the Excel from Resources
I added:

```
    `<copy todir="test/Resources/Data">
  <fileset dir="${Resources}/Data">
    <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
  </fileset>
</copy>`
```

the file copied but still fail.
Looks like code doesnt look in correct place..
Any idea?

full build.xml:

```
    <project name="TestNGTest" default="test" basedir=".">
<!-- Define <testng> task -->
  <taskdef name="testng" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="lib/testng-6.8.5.jar"/>
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>
   <property name="testdir" location="test" />
   <property name="srcdir" location="src" />
   <property name="libdir" location="lib" />
   <property name="full-compile" value="true" />
    <property name="Resources" location="Resources"/>


    <copy todir="test/Resources/Data">
      <fileset dir="${Resources}/Data">
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>

    <path id="classpath.base"/>



   <path id="classpath.test">
       <fileset dir="${libdir}">
         <include name="**/*.jar" />
      </fileset>
      <pathelement location="${testdir}" />
      <pathelement location="${srcdir}" />
      <path refid="classpath.base" />
   </path>
   <target name="clean" >
      <delete verbose="${full-compile}">
         <fileset dir="${testdir}" includes="**/*.class" />
      </delete>
   </target>
   <target name="compile" depends="clean">
      <javac srcdir="${srcdir}" destdir="${testdir}" 
         verbose="${full-compile}">
         <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
      </javac>
   </target>
   <target name="test" depends="compile">
    <testng outputdir=".test-output" classpathref="classpath.test"
        useDefaultListeners="false"
         listeners="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter,org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"> 
      <xmlfileset dir="." includes="testng.xml"/> 
    </testng>
   </target>
</project>'
```

Comment: Can you describe more through the xml file?

Comment: I added the build.xml

Comment: In my code i have:
`public String ExcelFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Resources/Data/TestDataCandex.xls";`
maybe it is the problem - after compilation he cannt find the file?

Comment: replace <copy todir="test/Resources/Data"> with <copy todir="${Resources}/Data">   | try this and let me know

Comment: Hi, now it even didn't copy the file. May be the reference in code should be another?

Comment: ok; then add <include name="**/*.xls" /> next to <exclude name="**/*.java"/>

Comment: But the file is copied correctly.
The code just doesnt know to use it.
But, while run it from IDE Ant it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem.
in code i use the System.getProperty("user.dir") and when running from ant it finds my "user" folder.
So i can manually put there the excel ant it works.
Now, i need to find the way to change the System.getProperty("user.dir") to something that points to projects root